# Dictionary<Guid, Guid> mapping from appsettings.json in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, appsettings

Working with VS 2017 on console application. When I use `Dictionary<string, Guid>` all works fine, however, when I use `Dictionary<Guid, Guid>` it doesn't map to AppSettings object (dict count is 0). Is there any way around it, rather then using `string` and converting it to `Guid` in the application?

*appsetting.json*

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "DictionaryTest": {
            "55789653-86A3-485C-95E8-5E23C3219130": "74F87895-4965-447A-B07F-F702573218B7", 
            "FB1E7891-B3C2-4E83-A6BF-7F321C11BFFA": "FA7892A9-7925-4150-82A7-5DD3213D1242"
        }
    }
}
```

*in Program.cs*

```
var appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Replace(@"file:\", "");

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile($@"{appPath}\appsettings.json");

Configuration = builder.Build();

appSettings = new AppSettings();
Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(appSettings);
```

When I use `Dictionary<string, Guid>` scenario there are 2 items in *`appSettings.DictionaryTest`* variable.

But when I use `Dictionary<Guid, Guid>` scenario there are 0 items in *`appSettings.DictionaryTest`* variable.

**`Dictionary<string, Guid>` scenario:**

*AppSettings.cs*

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, Guid> DictionaryTest { get; set; }
}
```

**`Dictionary<Guid, Guid>` scenario:**

*AppSettings.cs*

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public Dictionary<Guid, Guid> DictionaryTest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can image this having something to do with the fact appsettings is expecting a name value pair, apparently it's able to parse the value into a guid by default.

Comment: I thought GUID could be considered as valid name (key), but obviously it is not

Comment: What is your main concern against converting string to Guid programatically? `dict.ToDictionary(item => Guid.Parse(item.Key), item => item.Value);`

Answer (score 9):

At the moment, it appears that the Configuration Binder doesn't support `Guid` as a key type. The only supported types are `string` and `Enum` types.

This is actually stated in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.5/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L399):

```cs
if (keyType != typeof(string) && !keyTypeIsEnum)
{
    // We only support string and enum keys
    return;
}
```

But I don't think it is documented anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

While Kevin Eaton is correct and the official package doesn't support this, nothing stops you from shamelessly copying that file with the Extension methods and with just a couple of new lines of code, implement this yourself

The below works

```
//Install Nuget Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
//Install Nuget Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);
            var configuration = builder.Build();
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            var configurationSection = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            configurationSection.BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey(appSettings);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        }
    }
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public Dictionary<Guid, Guid> DictionaryTest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All I did was

1. Renamed the class to `CustomConfigurationBinderExtesions` so that the methods don't clash
2. Renamed the `Bind` method to `BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey`
3. Change `if (keyType != typeof(string) && !keyTypeIsEnum)` to
   `if (keyType != typeof(string) && keyType != typeof(Guid) && !keyTypeIsEnum)`
4. Added this

   `else if (keyType == typeof(Guid))`
   `{`
       `Guid key = Guid.Parse(child.Key);`
       `setter.SetValue(dictionary, item, new object[] { key });`
   `}`

Below is the full file(The original is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d927fcbb36131b8962d77d9f01bb3c6112072b95/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs))
(You can remove most of the code here and keep only what you need but I'm too lazy to do that :))

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static helper class that allows binding strongly typed objects to configuration values.
    /// </summary>
    public static class CustomConfigurationBinderExtesions
    {
        private const BindingFlags DeclaredOnlyLookup = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the configuration instance to a new instance of type T.
        /// If this configuration section has a value, that will be used.
        /// Otherwise binding by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the new instance to bind.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <returns>The new instance of T if successful, default(T) otherwise.</returns>
        //public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration)
        //    => configuration.Get<T>(_ => { });

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the configuration instance to a new instance of type T.
        /// If this configuration section has a value, that will be used.
        /// Otherwise binding by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the new instance to bind.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="configureOptions">Configures the binder options.</param>
        /// <returns>The new instance of T if successful, default(T) otherwise.</returns>
        //public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, Action<BinderOptions> configureOptions)
        //{
        //    if (configuration == null)
        //    {
        //        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        //    }

        //    object result = configuration.Get(typeof(T), configureOptions);
        //    if (result == null)
        //    {
        //        return default(T);
        //    }
        //    return (T)result;
        //}

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the configuration instance to a new instance of type T.
        /// If this configuration section has a value, that will be used.
        /// Otherwise binding by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type of the new instance to bind.</param>
        /// <returns>The new instance if successful, null otherwise.</returns>
        //public static object Get(this IConfiguration configuration, Type type)
        //    => configuration.Get(type, _ => { });

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the configuration instance to a new instance of type T.
        /// If this configuration section has a value, that will be used.
        /// Otherwise binding by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type of the new instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="configureOptions">Configures the binder options.</param>
        /// <returns>The new instance if successful, null otherwise.</returns>
        public static object Get(this IConfiguration configuration, Type type, Action<BinderOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            if (configuration == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            }

            var options = new BinderOptions();
            configureOptions?.Invoke(options);
            return BindInstance(type, instance: null, config: configuration, options: options);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the given object instance to the configuration section specified by the key by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the configuration section to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="instance">The object to bind.</param>
        public static void BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey(this IConfiguration configuration, string key, object instance)
            => configuration.GetSection(key).BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey(instance);

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the given object instance to configuration values by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="instance">The object to bind.</param>
        public static void BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey(this IConfiguration configuration, object instance)
            => configuration.BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey(instance, o => { });

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to bind the given object instance to configuration values by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="instance">The object to bind.</param>
        /// <param name="configureOptions">Configures the binder options.</param>
        public static void BindWhichSupportsGuidAsKey(this IConfiguration configuration, object instance, Action<BinderOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            if (configuration == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            }

            if (instance != null)
            {
                var options = new BinderOptions();
                configureOptions?.Invoke(options);
                BindInstance(instance.GetType(), instance, configuration, options);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts the value with the specified key and converts it to type T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to convert the value to.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the configuration section's value to convert.</param>
        /// <returns>The converted value.</returns>
        public static T GetValue<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, string key)
        {
            return GetValue(configuration, key, default(T));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts the value with the specified key and converts it to type T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to convert the value to.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the configuration section's value to convert.</param>
        /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value to use if no value is found.</param>
        /// <returns>The converted value.</returns>
        public static T GetValue<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, string key, T defaultValue)
        {
            return (T)GetValue(configuration, typeof(T), key, defaultValue);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts the value with the specified key and converts it to the specified type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration.</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type to convert the value to.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the configuration section's value to convert.</param>
        /// <returns>The converted value.</returns>
        public static object GetValue(this IConfiguration configuration, Type type, string key)
        {
            return GetValue(configuration, type, key, defaultValue: null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts the value with the specified key and converts it to the specified type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration.</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type to convert the value to.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the configuration section's value to convert.</param>
        /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value to use if no value is found.</param>
        /// <returns>The converted value.</returns>
        public static object GetValue(this IConfiguration configuration, Type type, string key, object defaultValue)
        {
            IConfigurationSection section = configuration.GetSection(key);
            string value = section.Value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                return ConvertValue(type, value, section.Path);
            }
            return defaultValue;
        }

        private static void BindNonScalar(this IConfiguration configuration, object instance, BinderOptions options)
        {
            if (instance != null)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in GetAllProperties(instance.GetType()))
                {
                    BindProperty(property, instance, configuration, options);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void BindProperty(PropertyInfo property, object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            // We don't support set only, non public, or indexer properties
            if (property.GetMethod == null ||
                (!options.BindNonPublicProperties && !property.GetMethod.IsPublic) ||
                property.GetMethod.GetParameters().Length > 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            object propertyValue = property.GetValue(instance);
            bool hasSetter = property.SetMethod != null && (property.SetMethod.IsPublic || options.BindNonPublicProperties);

            if (propertyValue == null && !hasSetter)
            {
                // Property doesn't have a value and we cannot set it so there is no
                // point in going further down the graph
                return;
            }

            propertyValue = BindInstance(property.PropertyType, propertyValue, config.GetSection(property.Name), options);

            if (propertyValue != null && hasSetter)
            {
                property.SetValue(instance, propertyValue);
            }
        }

        private static object BindToCollection(Type type, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            Type genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
            BindCollection(instance, genericType, config, options);
            return instance;
        }

        // Try to create an array/dictionary instance to back various collection interfaces
        private static object AttemptBindToCollectionInterfaces(Type type, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            if (!type.IsInterface)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Type collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(IReadOnlyList<>), type);
            if (collectionInterface != null)
            {
                // IEnumerable<T> is guaranteed to have exactly one parameter
                return BindToCollection(type, config, options);
            }

            collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>), type);
            if (collectionInterface != null)
            {
                Type dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments[0], type.GenericTypeArguments[1]);
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
                BindDictionary(instance, dictionaryType, config, options);
                return instance;
            }

            collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>), type);
            if (collectionInterface != null)
            {
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments[0], type.GenericTypeArguments[1]));
                BindDictionary(instance, collectionInterface, config, options);
                return instance;
            }

            collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<>), type);
            if (collectionInterface != null)
            {
                // IReadOnlyCollection<T> is guaranteed to have exactly one parameter
                return BindToCollection(type, config, options);
            }

            collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(ICollection<>), type);
            if (collectionInterface != null)
            {
                // ICollection<T> is guaranteed to have exactly one parameter
                return BindToCollection(type, config, options);
            }

            collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>), type);
            if (collectionInterface != null)
            {
                // IEnumerable<T> is guaranteed to have exactly one parameter
                return BindToCollection(type, config, options);
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static object BindInstance(Type type, object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            // if binding IConfigurationSection, break early
            if (type == typeof(IConfigurationSection))
            {
                return config;
            }

            var section = config as IConfigurationSection;
            string configValue = section?.Value;
            object convertedValue;
            Exception error;
            if (configValue != null && TryConvertValue(type, configValue, section.Path, out convertedValue, out error))
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    throw error;
                }

                // Leaf nodes are always reinitialized
                return convertedValue;
            }

            if (config != null && config.GetChildren().Any())
            {
                // If we don't have an instance, try to create one
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    // We are already done if binding to a new collection instance worked
                    instance = AttemptBindToCollectionInterfaces(type, config, options);
                    if (instance != null)
                    {
                        return instance;
                    }

                    instance = CreateInstance(type);
                }

                // See if its a Dictionary
                Type collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>), type);
                if (collectionInterface != null)
                {
                    BindDictionary(instance, collectionInterface, config, options);
                }
                else if (type.IsArray)
                {
                    instance = BindArray((Array)instance, config, options);
                }
                else
                {
                    // See if its an ICollection
                    collectionInterface = FindOpenGenericInterface(typeof(ICollection<>), type);
                    if (collectionInterface != null)
                    {
                        BindCollection(instance, collectionInterface, config, options);
                    }
                    // Something else
                    else
                    {
                        BindNonScalar(config, instance, options);
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }

        private static object CreateInstance(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("SR.Format(SR.Error_CannotActivateAbstractOrInterface, type)");
            }

            if (type.IsArray)
            {
                if (type.GetArrayRank() > 1)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("SR.Format(SR.Error_UnsupportedMultidimensionalArray, type)");
                }

                return Array.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType(), 0);
            }

            if (!type.IsValueType)
            {
                bool hasDefaultConstructor = type.GetConstructors(DeclaredOnlyLookup).Any(ctor => ctor.IsPublic && ctor.GetParameters().Length == 0);
                if (!hasDefaultConstructor)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("SR.Format(SR.Error_MissingParameterlessConstructor, type)");
                }
            }

            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("SR.Format(SR.Error_FailedToActivate, type), ex");
            }
        }

        private static void BindDictionary(object dictionary, Type dictionaryType, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            // IDictionary<K,V> is guaranteed to have exactly two parameters
            Type keyType = dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            Type valueType = dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments[1];
            bool keyTypeIsEnum = keyType.IsEnum;

            if (keyType != typeof(string) && keyType != typeof(Guid) && !keyTypeIsEnum)
            {
                // We only support string and enum keys
                return;
            }

            PropertyInfo setter = dictionaryType.GetProperty("Item", DeclaredOnlyLookup);
            foreach (IConfigurationSection child in config.GetChildren())
            {
                object item = BindInstance(
                    type: valueType,
                    instance: null,
                    config: child,
                    options: options);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (keyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        string key = child.Key;
                        setter.SetValue(dictionary, item, new object[] { key });
                    }
                    else if (keyType == typeof(Guid))
                    {
                        Guid key = Guid.Parse(child.Key);
                        setter.SetValue(dictionary, item, new object[] { key });
                    }
                    else if (keyTypeIsEnum)
                    {
                        object key = Enum.Parse(keyType, child.Key);
                        setter.SetValue(dictionary, item, new object[] { key });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void BindCollection(object collection, Type collectionType, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            // ICollection<T> is guaranteed to have exactly one parameter
            Type itemType = collectionType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            MethodInfo addMethod = collectionType.GetMethod("Add", DeclaredOnlyLookup);

            foreach (IConfigurationSection section in config.GetChildren())
            {
                try
                {
                    object item = BindInstance(
                        type: itemType,
                        instance: null,
                        config: section,
                        options: options);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        addMethod.Invoke(collection, new[] { item });
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }

        private static Array BindArray(Array source, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
        {
            IConfigurationSection[] children = config.GetChildren().ToArray();
            int arrayLength = source.Length;
            Type elementType = source.GetType().GetElementType();
            var newArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, arrayLength + children.Length);

            // binding to array has to preserve already initialized arrays with values
            if (arrayLength > 0)
            {
                Array.Copy(source, newArray, arrayLength);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    object item = BindInstance(
                        type: elementType,
                        instance: null,
                        config: children[i],
                        options: options);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        newArray.SetValue(item, arrayLength + i);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            return newArray;
        }

        private static bool TryConvertValue(Type type, string value, string path, out object result, out Exception error)
        {
            error = null;
            result = null;
            if (type == typeof(object))
            {
                result = value;
                return true;
            }

            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return TryConvertValue(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type), value, path, out result, out error);
            }

            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
            if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
            {
                try
                {
                    result = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error = new InvalidOperationException("SR.Format(SR.Error_FailedBinding, path, type), ex");
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (type == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                try
                {
                    result = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                }
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    error = new InvalidOperationException("SR.Format(SR.Error_FailedBinding, path, type), ex");
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static object ConvertValue(Type type, string value, string path)
        {
            object result;
            Exception error;
            TryConvertValue(type, value, path, out result, out error);
            if (error != null)
            {
                throw error;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static Type FindOpenGenericInterface(Type expected, Type actual)
        {
            if (actual.IsGenericType &&
                actual.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == expected)
            {
                return actual;
            }

            Type[] interfaces = actual.GetInterfaces();
            foreach (Type interfaceType in interfaces)
            {
                if (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
                    interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == expected)
                {
                    return interfaceType;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(Type type)
        {
            var allProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

            do
            {
                allProperties.AddRange(type.GetProperties(DeclaredOnlyLookup));
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            while (type != typeof(object));

            return allProperties;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting DictionaryTest as JSON and converting it to a Dictionary<Guid, Guid> manually with a JSON library. I wouldn't doubt if the conversion from appSettings isn't designed to handle that type of cast out of the box. Newtonsoft I know for sure can convert from JSON to a dictionary with a Guid key though. Right now I'm thinking something like this (using newtonsoft):

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public JObject DictionaryTest { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<Guid, Guid> DictionaryTestConvert 
    { 
        get { return JObject.toObject<Dictionary<Guid, Guid>>(DictionaryTestJson); } 
    }
}
```